# My localStorage value is not working the way I intend, why is that?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, darkmode

The darkmode toggling works the way I want to, but when I refresh the page when I'm on the darkmode the value goes "out of sync" so to speak and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
var state;
state = 1;
function store() {
    localStorage.getItem("state");
    if(state==0  || state == undefined){
        state = 1;
        localStorage.setItem("state", 1);
    }
    else if (state==1){
        state = 0;
        localStorage.setItem("state", 0);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("state", state);
}

function check(){
    x = localStorage.getItem("state");
    if(x==0){
        var element = document.body;
        element.classList.toggle("darkMode");
    }
    else if(x==null){
        alert("Your browser or its settings don't work with localStorage");
    }
}

function change(){
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("darkMode");
    var elem = document.getElementById("button");
    if (elem.innerHTML=="Dark mode"){
        elem.innerHTML = "Light mode";
    }
    else{
        elem.innerHTML = "Dark mode";
    }
}
window.onload = check;
```

Comment: The `check()` function will alert an error the first time you run the code, because nothing has been save to `localStorage` yet.

Comment: You don't update `state` or `localStorage` in `change()`

Comment: Know that `getItem` will return null if the key being fetched is not found, not that the browser does not support darkmode.